# How to get a part of a string in java?

Tags: java, string

Basically, I have these strings:

```
/path/to/Pbox01/file1_#$%encryp
/path/to/Pbox01/file4_#$%encryp
/path/to/Pbox02/file2_#$%encryp
```

And I want to get ONLY `file1`, `file4`, `file2` for each iteration. Those are filenames, and they can be anything(like `file`, `stack`, `blahblahblah`. First I want to get the part after the last slash - this is the part I'm having biggest problems with. The ending is hardset, so I want to trim _#$%encryp, which is 10 characters - for that I'll use:

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length()-10);
}
```

So, to summarize, the question is: How can I get the part of the string after the last `/`?

Comment: Given that it's a filename, I'd start with `java.io.File`. Alternatively, `String.lastIndexOf` and `String.substring` if you really want to.

Comment: It is a filename, but I'm not really working with files, but filenames or filepaths, that's why I don't consider `java.io.File`. Am I wrong with my line of thought?

Comment: Yes, because `java.io.File` is precisely an abstract filename. It doesn't require the file to *exist*.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use lastIndexOf, but thanks nonetheless, I'll probably use your advice too sometime later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might use [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) like,

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
    return s;
  }
  return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, s.length() - 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void changetomain(String [] args) {

    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    paths.add("/path/to/Pbox01/file1_#$%encryp");
    paths.add("/path/to/Pbox01/file2_#$%encryp");
    paths.add("/path/to/Pbox01/file4_#$%encryp");

    ArrayList<String> filenames = getFilenames(paths);  

}

private ArrayList<String> getFilenames(ArrayList<String> paths) {
    ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String path : paths) {
        String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.indexOf("_"));
        filenames.add(filename);
    }

    return filenames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use something like this,

```
String[] strArray = str.split("/");
```

Then take only the last value in the array to process further.